# evento ondblclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Estoy realizando una aplicación en JSP para hacer y responder preguntas. Intento hacer una función para poder  editar una respuesta, mi idea es que el usuario de doble clic sobre la respuesta a editar y se muestren los botones para editar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función como tal en JavaScript  funciona, mi problema es que para poner todas las respuestas publicadas en esa pregunta utilizo un ciclo y una lista así que cuando hago clic en  la respuesta 3  por ejemplo siempre activa los botones de la respuesta 1 y también toma los valores de la pregunta 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No importa si doy clic en la segunda o tercera respuesta siempre se activan los botones de la respuesta 1.

Éste es mi código:

```
<%                     
ArrayList<Answer> Respuestas=DB.MostrarRespuestas(idPregunta); //lista de respuestas a la pregunta
ArrayList<Usuario> likes; //Almacena la lista de las personas a quienes les gusta una respuesta especifica                            
for(int i=0;i<Respuestas.size();i++) //ciclo para colocar todas las respuestas
{
    out.println("<div class=row>");//Div general

    out.println("<h5>"+Respuestas.get(i).getUser()+" answered :</h5>");//usuario que publico la respuesta
    out.println("<p>Date: "+Respuestas.get(i).getFecha()+"</p>");// fecha en que la publico

    out.println("<div class=col-md-1>");//Div foto de usuario
    out.println("<a href='../user/user.jsp?wiw="+Respuestas.get(i).getWiw()+"'><img src='../img/user/"+Respuestas.get(i).getWiw()+".png' class='img-circle img-responsive'></a>");//Imagen del usuario
    out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div foto de usuario


    out.println("<div class=col-md-1>");//Div Like

    out.println("<form  action='../Like' method='post'>");//formulario  like
    likes=DB.Usuarios_Liked(Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer());//Obtiene la lista de las personas a quienes les gusta la respuesta
    String habilitar="";//habilita o deshabilita el boton

    for(int j=0;j<likes.size();j++)//recorre toda la lista
        if(likes.get(j).getWiw().equals(user.getWiw()))//si el wiw del usaurio que accedio al sistema aparece en la lista
            habilitar="disabled"; //bloquea el boton like

    out.println("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' disable='true' "+habilitar+" >");//boton de like                                                    
    out.println("<center><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up' aria-hidden='true'></i>  Like "+likes.size()+"<center>");//numero de likes que tiene la respuesta                                                    
    out.println("</button>");

    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idAnswer' value="+Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer()+">");//id de la respuesta a l que se le dio like (oculto)
    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='wiw' value="+user.getWiw()+">");//wiw del usuario que le dio like(oculto)                                                
    out.println("<center><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' style='font-size:100%' >Ver</a></center>");//despliega la lista de personas a quienes les gusta la respuesta                                                                                                                                            
    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idQuestion' value="+idPregunta+">");//id de la pregunta a la que pertenece la respueta (oculto)
    out.println("</form>");//Cierra formulario  like
    out.println("</div>");// Cierra Div Like


    out.println("<div class='col-md-9'>");//Div texto respuesta                                                                                
    out.println("<textarea style='margin-bottom:25px' class='form-control' readonly='true' id='comentario' ondblclick='EditQuestion()'>");                                    
    String texto=Respuestas.get(i).getText();
    out.println(texto);
    out.print("</textarea>");                                                                                                                                                           
    out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div texto respuesta

    out.println("</div>");//Cierra Div general                                                                                               

    out.println("<center>");
    out.println("<div class='row' style='display:none' id='botones'>");//Div para editar la respuesta
    out.println("<form action='../EditRespuesta' method='post'>");
    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='texto' value='"+texto+"'>");//texto de la pregunta que se edito
    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idRespuesta' value='"+Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer()+"'>");//id de la respuesta a modificar
    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idPregunta' value='"+Respuestas.get(i).getIdQuestion()+"'>");//id de la pregunta a que pertenece dicha respuesta
    out.println("<div>");
    out.println("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' >Guardar</button>");//boton guardar
    out.println("<button type='button' onclick='EditCancel()' class='btn btn-default' >Cancelar</button>"); //boton cancelar                                                                       
    out.println("</div>");

    out.println("</form>");                                        
    out.println("</div>");
    out.println("</center>");

    }
%>
```

Función de JavaScript

```
<script>
//Funcion para enviar el texto de la respuesta al modal               
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#ModalEditPregunta').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;            
        $(e.currentTarget).find('#texto').val(id);            
    });
}); 

function EditQuestion() {            
    var botones=document.getElementById("botones");
    botones.style.display="inline";
}

function EditCancel(){
    var botones=document.getElementById("botones");
    botones.style.display="none";
}     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El problema es que estás duplicando IDs**. En cada fila  que insertas dentro del bucle `for` estás haciendo esto:

```
out.println("<div class='row' style='display:none' id='botones'>");//Div para editar la respuesta
out.println("<form action='../EditRespuesta' method='post'>");
out.println("<input type='hidden' name='texto' value='"+texto+"'>");//texto de la pregunta que se edito
out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idRespuesta' value='"+Respuestas.get(i).getIdAnswer()+"'>");//id de la respuesta a modificar
out.println("<input type='hidden' name='idPregunta' value='"+Respuestas.get(i).getIdQuestion()+"'>");//id de la pregunta a que pertenece dicha respuesta
out.println("<div>");
out.println("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' >Guardar</button>");//boton guardar
out.println("<button type='button' onclick='EditCancel()' class='btn btn-default' >Cancelar</button>"); //boton cancelar                                                                       
out.println("</div>");
```

Lo que causará que todos los juegos de botones en todas las filas tengan el id "botones". Entonces cuando en tu código JavaScript haces esto:

```
var botones=document.getElementById("botones");
botones.style.display="inline";
```

El navegador sólo toma la primera ocurrencia del ID bottones y lo muestra. Aunque hayas pulsado en la segunda o tercera fila.

**La solución: no dupliques IDs en tu código, usa clases para elementos que sabes que se van a repetir O crea IDs únicos** (por ejemplo añadiendo el índice del bucle al ID):

```
// nota: no he probado este código y puede fallar
out.println("<div class='row' style='display:none' id='botones" + i + "'>");
```

Entonces en la función en la que se hace el doble click, pasarías el ID de la fila que se ha pulsado (o la del ID del botón de cancelar):

```
function EditQuestion(fila) {            
    var botones=document.getElementById("botones" + fila);
    botones.style.display="inline";
}

function EditCancel(fila){
    var botones=document.getElementById("botones" + fila);
    botones.style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto   gracias